# Laravel 5.2 Query String Parameter Validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am currently doing a small project to learn some laravel validation and ran into a problem.
The API endpoint is `api/test/schoolbook?start=` and my validation is
`'start' => ['date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s']`

While this works like a charm and sorts the schoolbooks by a start year, i think my validation has some error. It validates if start is equal to the defined date format, all good. but if i now parse just `?start=`without any thing, it still goes through, but doesn't throw an error message (it just returns everything without sorting)

Is there a way i can validate this better and prevent the query string parameter to be empty?

If `start` is not passed, it should return all the records, so i cant make it required really. 
So the scenarios are:

`?start=date` is passed in the right format and returns all the schoolbooks by the passed date,
`?start=date` is not passed and returns all the records in the database
`?start=` should also return 'has to be in date format validation'

Thank you!

The Controller:

```
    public function findSchoolbook(
         SchoolBookRequest $request,
    ) : JsonResponse {

    $schoolbook = $this->schoolkbool->sort($paramBag);
        $response = $this->transformer()->paginator($schoolbook);

    return $this->response($response);
}
```

The ParamBg method i use

```
private function getParamBag(SchoolBookRequest $request) : ParamBag
{
    return ParamBag::create()
        ->setPage($request->get('page'))
        ->setPerPage($request->get('per_page'))
        ->setStartDate($request->get('start_at'))
}
```

The Request

```
  class SchoolBookRequest extends Request
{
    public function rules() : array
    {
         return [
             'start_at' => ['date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s']
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `'start' => ['required', 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s']` or use the current date if no date is passed?

Comment: share your codes so we can help. It's hard if there's nothing to debug

Comment: @TheFallen I would like to return all the records, if start is not passed :) Sorry, should have said that in my previous post

Comment: Then please share the controller code you are referring to, so we can adapt it towards the answer you seek :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should only filter in start date when present in the request:

```
private function getParamBag(SchoolBookRequest $request) : ParamBag
{
    $parambag = ParamBag::create()
        ->setPage($request->get('page'))
        ->setPerPage($request->get('per_page'))

    if ($request->has('start_at')) {
         $parambag = $parambag->setStartDate($request->get('start_at'));
    }

   return $parambag;
}
```